# Difficulty in understanding decorator output using typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I am having hard time understanding this code:

```
function Console(target) {
  console.log('Our decorated class', target);
}

@Console
class ExampleClass {
  constructor() {
    console.log('Yo!');
  }
}
```

I got output as `Our decorated class [Function: ExampleClass`] after compiling and running using node why is it that i didnt get `Yo!`.Can you explain to me this code, I saved it as

```
decorators.ts
```

compiled using tsc --target ES5 --experimentalDecorators decorators.ts
and then ran node decorators.js

documentation is too tough to understand

I am totally confused in angular we dont need to instantiate a class and everything works fine but here we have to.can you please tell me why we dont need to instantiate a class in typescript

Comment: You didn't call the code that actually says Yo and also:

further reading of what decorators are https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#class-decorators

Comment: @Pandelis i didnt get you how to call that

Comment: You'll need a statement like `new Console()` somewhere to get `Yo!`

Comment: @Evert thanks i am hard time understanding about decorators,can you please explain to me the work flow of above code]

Comment: @Evert but example class is having a constructor right

Comment: @Evert then why cant it print Yo

Comment: what is target in this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`console.log('Yo!')` is in the *constructor* of `ExampleClass`. But you have not actually constructed any instances of `ExampleClass`. You have only decorated the class object itself.

There is nothing special about a class decorator that would run the constructor of the class it decorates unless you specifically run code that instantiates it.

---

If you add `new ExampleClass()` to the end of your code, you will get the `"Yo!"` that you expect.

Comment: I am totally confused in angular we dont need to instantiate a class and everything works fine but here we have to.can you please tell me why we dont need to instantiate a class in angular

Comment: I'm no angular expert, but are you talking about dependency injection? That means that you declare that you want a type of object, and then Angular instantiates that for you, then passes it to your code. The angular provided decorators probably have logic that registers them with the dependency injection framework and then instantiates them as needed. But there is nothing about a class decorator that would do that unless you make that decorator do that. `@Console class MyClass {}` is really just syntax sugar for `Console(class MyClass {})`

Comment: @somanraj, about decorators, take a look to https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/javascript-make-your-code-cleaner-with-decorators-d34fc72af947 and https://netbasal.com/inspiration-for-custom-decorators-in-angular-95aeb87f072c